# Zooming a landscape image captured from camera to use it in portrait

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, camera

In my app i am capturing `image` from camera using `UIImagePicker` and than croping it. But problem is that when I capture image from camera in landscape mode, at the time of croping it in potrait mode the blackbox is shown in image.

**Image is captured in landscape mode -**

[image]

**and at the time of using that image the black box is shown at upper and bottom part of image as shown in below image -**

[image]

but I want to remove that black parts so that `image` covers whole area.

How can i do this ?

Comment: As per my knowledge this is not possible with image picker controller as by default it adjusts the image in aspect fit mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you cropping the image with 
`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);`
Or else can you share how exactly you are doing the cropping?

When image is taken from the `UIImagePickerController` in landscape mode, you need to check the orientation property of the UIImage. ie `[image orientation];`

if the orientation value is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`, interchange between the rect width and height. And then crop it.

Comment: thanks for reply. But Can you explain how to interchange between the rect width and height ?

Comment: Change like this when in landscape `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y,rect.size.height,rect.size.width));` I Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again for reply. I have tried your code but it doesnt give orientation of an image.It shows the warning "UIImage may not respond to orientation"

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect Image:(UIImage *)originalImage ImageOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation
{

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, rect);

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0f orientation:imageOrientation];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return result;
}
```